# EntityFramework Core: Migration doesn't add new fields to DB and create wrong migration file

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, console-application, database-migration

I'm writing my dotnet console project, using Entity Framework Core, when I added new fields in my Model, created migration and updated my DB, the new fields did not appear in the database and the migration file looked wrong because it wants to create already existed fields and don't create the new fields

Here is my model class:

```
public class Book
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string? Title { get; set; }
    public int Pages { get; set; }
    public Genre? Genre { get; set; } //this field was added
    public Author? Author { get; set; } //this field was added
    public Publisher? Publisher { get; set; } //this field was added
    public Guid GenreId { get; set; }
    public Guid AuthorId { get; set; }
    public Guid PublisherId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PublishedDate { get; set; }
}
```

The DbContext file:

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; } = null!;

    public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; } = null!;

    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; } = null!;

    public DbSet<Publisher> Publishers { get; set; } = null!;

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
        var config = builder.Build();
        var connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    }
}
```

The migration file:

```
/// <inheritdoc />
public partial class NewBookFieldAdded : Migration
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Authors",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Authors", x => x.Id);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Genres",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Genres", x => x.Id);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Publishers",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Publishers", x => x.Id);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Books",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
                Title = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                Pages = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                GenreId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
                AuthorId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
                PublisherId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
                PublishedDate = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Books", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Books_Authors_AuthorId",
                    column: x => x.AuthorId,
                    principalTable: "Authors",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Books_Genres_GenreId",
                    column: x => x.GenreId,
                    principalTable: "Genres",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Books_Publishers_PublisherId",
                    column: x => x.PublisherId,
                    principalTable: "Publishers",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Books_AuthorId",
            table: "Books",
            column: "AuthorId");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Books_GenreId",
            table: "Books",
            column: "GenreId");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Books_PublisherId",
            table: "Books",
            column: "PublisherId");
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Books");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Authors");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Genres");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Publishers");
    }
}
```

And after migration Package Manager Console prints:

```
There is already an object named 'Authors' in the database.
```

Comment: Migration has two modes 1) Create 2) Update.  You are using Create which will give an error if object already exists.  I've seen errors like this if a field is a key in one table an not in another table.

Comment: @jdweng but how can I update? All, that I found was: 'Add-Migration <Migration name>' and 'Update-Database'?

Comment: The second one.  Add is the create mode.

Comment: @jdweng - you're wrong. [Migrations Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=vs). `Add-Migration` must be called every time.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your migration. The table already contained the foreign keys `GenreId, AuthorId, PublisherId` needed for relationships. Adding navigation properties only adds usability to the C# code. But the schema of the tables does not change.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov : Migration only has to be called when classes in c# are modified to map the classes to the database.  If you are just doing queries you do not perform a migration.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov : The link says Update-Database (Add-Migration is not needed) "That's all there is to it - your application is ready to run on your new database, and you didn't need to write a single line of SQL. Note that this way of applying migrations is ideal for local development, but is less suitable for production environments - see the Applying Migrations page for more info."